# Not able to send two String datatype from frontend to backend

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have been trying to send an array of objects to backend from frontend using reactjs, nodejs and MySQL. For some reason, my String data is not going. I am getting a void in the database table. Start Date and End Date are getting visible exactly how I want it to be. Can someone please help me with this issue. Also my very first work experience that I am filling in workExperience array is coming out to be NULL.

The Values that I am using in the function are as follows:

```
  const [ agencyName, setAgencyName ] = useState("");
  const [ prevRole, setPrevRole ] = useState("");
  const [ startDate, setStartDate ] = useState(null);
  const [ endDate, setEndDate ] = useState(null);
  const [ workExperience, setWorkExperience] = useState([]);
```

The function that is handling the data flow to backend is as follows:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const formattedWorkExperience = workExperience.map((item) => (
      {
        agencyName: item.agencyName,
        prevRole: item.prevRole,
        startDate: item.startDate,
        endDate: item.endDate
      }
    ))
    const newEmployee = {
         firstName, 
         lastName: LastName, 
         DateOfBirth,
         contactNumber,
         roleOption,
         workExperience: formattedWorkExperience,
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/dataentry/newemployee", newEmployee)
      if(res) {
        console.log(res)
      } else {
        console.log("Error found in axios posting method.")
      }
    } catch (error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

backend:

```
//Create a new Employee basic Details
router.post("/newemployee", async (req, res) => {
    const { workExperience } = req.body;

      if(workExperience && Array.isArray(workExperience)) {
        // Construct the SQL query to insert data into `work experience` table
        const query2 = "INSERT INTO `work experience` (`Sl. No.`, `Agency Name`, `Role`, `Start Date`, `End Date`, `Emp_Id`) VALUES ?"

        const workExperienceValues = workExperience.map((exp) => [
          null,
          exp.AgencyName,
          exp.prevRole,
          dayjs(exp.StartDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          dayjs(exp.EndDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          employeeId
        ]);

        db.query(query2, [workExperienceValues], (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Error inserting work experience data', workExperienceValues);
          }

          res.status(200).send('Data inserted successfully');
        })
      }
    });
})
```

I have checked the API using PostMan and I am being able to send the data and everything is getting visible.
Now upon debugging and trial and error I noticed that when i don't use `formattedWorkExperience` constant, my `Role` column gets the data and only `Agency Name` column remains void. The reason why the above code did not had the item is because i had removed that code.

I tried mapping as well but upon mapping also both my `Agency name` & `Role` column gets void data.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. What data do you expect to be present in the request and what data do you actually get? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to directly inspect the request body

Comment: I have made the necessary edits. The reason I had not used items was because it was breaking the whole code. Now I have reverted back to the previous version, and the items is now working but the agencyName and prevRole is showing NULL values though upon debugging and using console.log() they are not null.

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between `agencyName` (the property in your request data) and `AgencyName` (the property you're trying to insert). JS is case-sensitive. I suggest you stick to one naming convention and try not to mix them

Comment: Thanks alot @Philisonstrike!! It finally worked!!

Answer (score -1):

```
const formattedWorkExperience = workExperience.map((item) => ({
  agencyName: item.agencyName,
  prevRole: item.prevRole,
  startDate,
  endDate,
}));
```

**try this map method**

Comment: I tried this but now my backend code is breaking and throwing an error "Coloumn 'Agency Name' cannot be null". Though upon using `console.log(agencyName), I can see the values and it is not NULL.

Answer (score -1):

```
const formattedWorkExperience = workExperience.map((item) => {
  const agencyName = item.agencyName || ''; // Provide a default value if agencyName is null or undefined
  const prevRole = item.prevRole;
  const startDate = item.startDate;
  const endDate = item.endDate;

  return {
    agencyName,
    prevRole,
    startDate,
    endDate,
  };
});
```

**try this**